# (bootstrap) Input-group class doesn't allow me to centerize inputs in modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why can't I centerize my inputs when I use input-group? 
With input-group: http://jsfiddle.net/mr4pgk52/

```
<input style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Without input-group: http://jsfiddle.net/56ss9e0c/

```
<div class="input-group><input style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
```

Comment: You might link the image from a public image upload service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add

```
.input-group{ margin:0 auto;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mr4pgk52/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Btw, is it important to use input-group?

Comment: i didnt if it is important or not but the solution of your question is above .i think other can tell just wait a little

Answer (score 0):

try to update

```
.input-group{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It works but I also want to know, is it important to use input-group? Thanks for your help! ^^